# As a server in http4s, how can I find out whether a websocket connection has been closed or not?

Tags: scala, websocket, server

This is an attempt at trying to figure out the best way to be aware as a server when the websocket connection has closed:

```
"Is there a way to know that the connection has closed?" in async {
    val receivedClosedFrame = Promise[Unit]
    val mock = HttpService {
        case req@GET -> Root =>
            val sink: Sink[Task, WebSocketFrame] = Process.constant {
                case f => Task.delay{receivedClosedFrame.success(())}
            }
            WS(Exchange(Process.empty, sink))
    }
    Http4s.withWebSocketService(mock, 9090) { uri =>
        for {
            conn <- Connection.connect(uri)
            _ <- conn.disconnect()
            _ <- Task.delay(Await.ready(receivedClosedFrame.future, 3.seconds))
        } yield ()
    }
}
```

In the above example, the test times out because the server does not ever receive a `WebSocketFrame`. How can the server know whether or not the client requested the connection be closed?